# C# Unexpected behavior in DataGridView columns

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

Using Visual Studio, I created a data grid view that allow the users to modify some data. Unfortunately, when the application is released as an executable, this form seems to add the data in new columns instead of using the designated ones. Like this:

Error as below

[image]

I am not able to replicate the error in debug mode, but here is a picture of how it's really supposed to look.

Expected behavior as below

[image]

Here is part of the code where the gridview is being created and populated.

```
        //child name column
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        nameColumn.Name = "cName";
        nameColumn.HeaderText = "Child Name";
        nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "cName";
        nameColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);

        //child layer column
        var LayerColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        LayerColumn.Name = "cLayer";
        LayerColumn.HeaderText = "Child Layer";
        LayerColumn.DataPropertyName = "cLayer";
        LayerColumn.AutoComplete = true;
        LayerColumn.ValueMember = "cLayer";
        LayerColumn.ValueType = typeof(string);
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(LayerColumn);

        // parent name column
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn parentColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        parentColumn.HeaderText = "Parent Name";
        parentColumn.Name = "cParent";
        parentColumn.DataPropertyName = "cParent";
        parentColumn.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(parentColumn);

        //parent layer column
        var pLayerColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        pLayerColumn.Name = "pLayer";
        pLayerColumn.HeaderText = "Parent Layer";
        pLayerColumn.DataPropertyName = "pLayer";
        pLayerColumn.AutoComplete = true;
        pLayerColumn.ValueMember = "pLayer";
        pLayerColumn.ValueType = typeof(string);
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(pLayerColumn);

        //child name column
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn nameColumn2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        nameColumn2.Name = "cName";
        nameColumn2.HeaderText = "Feat 1 Name";
        nameColumn2.DataPropertyName = "cName";
        nameColumn2.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(nameColumn2);

        //child layer column
        var LayerColumn2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        LayerColumn2.Name = "cLayer";
        LayerColumn2.HeaderText = "Feat 1 Layer";
        LayerColumn2.DataPropertyName = "cLayer";
        LayerColumn2.AutoComplete = true;
        LayerColumn2.ValueMember = "cLayer";
        LayerColumn2.ValueType = typeof(string);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(LayerColumn2);

        // parent name column
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn parentColumn2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        parentColumn2.HeaderText = "Feat 2 Name";
        parentColumn2.Name = "cParent";
        parentColumn2.DataPropertyName = "cParent";
        parentColumn2.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(parentColumn2);

        //parent layer column
        var pLayerColumn2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        pLayerColumn2.Name = "pLayer";
        pLayerColumn2.HeaderText = "Feat 2 Layer";
        pLayerColumn2.DataPropertyName = "pLayer";
        pLayerColumn2.AutoComplete = true;
        pLayerColumn2.ValueMember = "pLayer";
        pLayerColumn2.ValueType = typeof(string);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(pLayerColumn2);

        _p = new Processor(this);

        _characteristicViewModels = new BindingList<RelativeCharacteristicViewModel>();

        dataGridView.DataSource = _characteristicViewModels;

        foreach (var c in characteristics)
        {
            foreach (var d in c.Value)
            {
                _characteristicViewModels.Add(new RelativeCharacteristicViewModel
                {
                    cName = c.Key.name,
                    cLayer = c.Key.layer,
                    cParent = d.name,
                    pLayer = d.layer
                });
            }
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cLayerColumn = dataGridView.Columns["cLayer"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        if (cLayerColumn != null)
        {
            layers.ForEach(p => cLayerColumn.Items.Add(p));
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn parentLayerColumn = dataGridView.Columns["pLayer"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        if (parentLayerColumn != null)
        {
            layers.ForEach(p => parentLayerColumn.Items.Add(p));
        }

        _p = new Processor(this);

        _characteristicViewModels2 = new BindingList<RelativeCharacteristicViewModel>();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = _characteristicViewModels2;

        foreach (var c in characteristics2)
        {
            foreach (var d in c.Value)
            {
                _characteristicViewModels2.Add(new RelativeCharacteristicViewModel
                {
                    cName = c.Key.name,
                    cLayer = c.Key.layer,
                    cParent = d.name,
                    pLayer = d.layer
                });
            }
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cLayerColumn2 = dataGridView1.Columns["cLayer"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        if (cLayerColumn2 != null)
        {
            layers.ForEach(p => cLayerColumn2.Items.Add(p));
        }

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn parentLayerColumn2 = dataGridView1.Columns["pLayer"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        if (parentLayerColumn2 != null)
        {
            layers.ForEach(p => parentLayerColumn2.Items.Add(p));
        }
```